# XCode live issues lag behind

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I have had this issue that I edit a line of code and it takes XCode like 5 seconds to realize the error has gone away or the other way around. I have the new MacBook Pro M1 Max and I thought it was a problem with my old Macbook but it seems that it isn't.

I can't find any information online on that topic. Is this how it is supposed to be?

**More detail:**

I have a line of code and XCode detects an error and colors this line red. I fix the error in the line or delete it entirely and it takes a good few seconds until XCode removes the Error from the line. I never had an issue like that with another IDE. With larger code segments the problem only seems to get worse. I presume this delay is some kind of feature, but it makes editing code quite slow (for me).

Comment: I think that's the problem of Xcode itself. You can build the project again when you finish editing. Xcode will pick up the errors/warnings quicker. `cmd` + `b` will be your good friend :)

Comment: [this](https://www.avanderlee.com/optimization/analysing-build-performance-xcode-10/) is a really helpful article. Coding habits can really slow down compiling. Type checking is a really time consumer.